# need to convert Int value into double having one digit after point

Tags: c#, type-conversion

simply I have two Int variables and an array of type double

```
int a=2; int b=3;

double[] result =  new double[2];
```

now i need to add these variables a,b into the array result but they should be added with precision one

2.0 and 3.0

```
result[0]=a; 
result[1]=b;
```

End result

```
result[0] have value 2.0 and 
result[1] have value 3.0
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: I tried   result[0]= Math.Round(a,1) and convert a to .ToString("0.0") and than to double. also try to add 0.0 in a and than added to result but all vain

Comment: What you mean by "all vain", did you get any errors, how you check that result is as expected?

Comment: `2.0` and `2.000000000000000` are the same number, How you choose to visualize it when you output it would be the difference.  Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Fabio means no success, I will check results by Console.WriteLine()

Comment: Try to check result by `Console.WriteLine(value, "0.0")`

Comment: @RetiredNinja its just a scenario, I will check the result by Console.Write(). I will use this in some calculation methods.

Comment: @Fabio Console.WriteLine() is only to check results.  I have to use result array in some other calculation. needs result inside the array

Comment: Result inside array has one digit after the point, actually it has as much points as you like when you want to display it.

Comment: @Fabio displaying result means just checking the result. the actual task is that result array should contain 2.0 and 3.0.

Comment: The number of decimals is not a feature of `double` itself (which is just a number, and 2 and 2.0 are the same number), but a feature of formatting it for output (as @Fabio wrote).

Answer (score 1):

A double in C# has a precision of approximately 16 digits. You cannot change this, but you can probably be sure that your 2 and 3 integers are 2.0 and 3.0 when you assigned them to doubles

In short, you don't have any question to answer; you've already done what you hoped to do. Your numbers are already what you want them to be

As has been pointed out in the comments, if you want them to be presented in a particular way on screen then you format them to a string when emitting them to screen, such as `yourDouble.ToString("0.0")`.

This is exactly the same concept as with dates - the strings "2020-01-01" and "01 Jan 2020 00:00" represent exactly the same moment in time and as a human when you read them you understand it's midnight on Jan 1st, year 2020.. They are just formatted differently.

2 (integer), 2.00000000 (float) and 2.0000000000000000 (double) are all the same value, they're just formatted differently. Inhabitants of one country might write have a thousands separator that is a `.` and a decimal separator that is a `,` and write  "2,0".. but it is still the same value

Comment: got your point. then my question is that you say "but you can probably be sure that your 2 and 3 integers are 2.0 and 3.0 when you assigned them to doubles". How would I convert 2 and 3 to 2.0 and 3.0 while assigning them to double?

Comment: You already did the conversion when you assigned. I said "probably" because not every number is exactly representable as a double. For example, if you do `int a = 6; double b = a; b *= 0.1;` you might expect your double to be 0.6, but it'll actually be `0.60000000000000009`.. But as you're only printing it to 1 decimal place, it doesn't matter